# In Oracle, How many parallel jobs can be created with N number of CPUs?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, parallel-processing, query-optimization

In Oracle, Based on the CPU cores / counts, How many parallel jobs can be created? And Additionally, What will be the impact if Parallel DML and DDL are enabled in all parallel jobs.

I have 200+ different independent procedures to execute. Currently They are in serial mode. I am testing to run them in Parallel jobs. But I am not sure How to decide how many parallel jobs should I create. Additionally, I have to repeatedly execute this in different servers which have different number of CPU cores. For Now I am running 4 jobs parallel in QUAD core. Furthermore, Current procedures already have PARALLEL(8) hints in queries, will the CPU be overloaded because of parallel jobs.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  Are you asking about the maximum number of parallel sessions based on database parameters?  Or are you looking for guidance on how many sessions *should* be running?

Comment: I have updated my question Jon, sorry for confusion. actually I need guidance to decide how many sessions?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your jobs are doing.  As a very, very rough rule of thumb, I wouldn't want more than 2*N sessions (including the parallel slaves started by any parallel DML).  If your sessions are CPU bound, that limit my be much lower.  Realistically, as with anything else, you'd want to benchmark in your environment and adjust based on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of those things you can ONLY determine via trial and error. Rules may be a guidance, but there's so many parameters that come into play here. Have a good method of controlling your level of parallelism, set up monitoring from which you can detail into separate CPU usage, and test !

Additionally : test, test, test.